# Firefox 17+ infinite throbber

Tags: jquery, firefox, jquery-cycle

while testing a new website i found a problem/bug with Firefox 17, 18 and 19 (beta). I made a image rotation with jquery cycle2, this rotation seems to cause that Firefox never finish to load the website (infinite Throbber, can get loading time from Firebug).

I made a testcase for my problem and even found a solution but want to know why Firefox dislikes my first code (index_01.html).

All other browsers work, even Firefox 16.

Here is the testcase -> http://www.mediafire.com/?ccneccr3czccac4